# What is the grammar name

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

Hey i am not an English speaker and i have and easy question the nouns fish and shop etc when you make it verb its fishing shopping the question is there a grammar or schedule that shows how to turn names into verbs

Comment: The "unmodified" forms are verbs as well as nouns *(I fish for compliments, I shop for groceries)*. The ***-ing*** forms can be used as straightforward verbs *(Stop fishing and go shopping)*, but they can also be "gerunds" (verb forms used as nouns) in contexts such as *I think shopping is boring, but fishing is fun*.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... The short answer is that I have not seen an easy table or rule to help with this. Some nouns can also be used as verbs, while others cannot or are not commonly used in that way. For example, the two that you used do work.

> The girl stopped by the shop to pick up eggs and milk. Her mother often asks her to go shopping on her way home from school.
>
> I am making fish for dinner tonight, I think I will season it with rosemary and pepper. I do not really like fishing myself, it is such a boring sport.

However, some nouns cannot become verbs.

> I always take an apple in my lunch when I go to work- they are healthy and delicious!

But there is no such thing as "to apple" or "appling." You might "pick an apple" or "go apple picking" or you could "harvest some apples." or "slice the apples" or do any other number of things to apples. But "apple" cannot be used as a verb.

Like most other things in English, there are few steady rules that always apply. If you want to know if there is a common verb form of a specific noun, feel free to ask another question!